# Floated parent causes jquery performance stutter/lag in firefox 8

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Sorry if this is a known bug but I've been trying to figure this out for some hours now (Google searches and my own testing).

- I have a parent container that's being floated right.
- The parent container consists of 10 divs that each contain an h3 and another div. When clicked, the animate() event is triggered and the div is shown. Basically an accordion style setup.
- I've narrowed down the performance stutter/lag to the **float:right**
  css attribute on the parent container.
- Removing this causes the events to become smooth as they should.
- But doing so breaks my layout. I have also tested it in safari 5.0, ie8, and chrome and all events are smooth when the float:right is on. Firefox is my only problem. Also, Using slideToggle() gave me the same lagging results. Is this something that's a known issue with firefox/jquery and floats? I'm using the current jquery library.

Comment: Yeah, people have noted this in the past, see http://alexw.me/2010/12/firefox-problems-with-javascript-animation/. Took us hours of debugging to find the cause of the laggy animations in a project of ours. All I can say is try to find a way of doing it without floats.

Comment: I agree with Christian. I've been down this path before as well, and instead of using floats we ended up using position:absolute, and an easing plugin. It worked perfectly. It's really a pain.

Comment: Seems using display:inline-block; instead of floats doesn't make a difference either. The easing plugin is already being used and also didn't make a difference. Positioning absolute makes sense and works but I'm not a fan of positioning anything that shouldn't need it. Looks as though I need to change the position or live with the lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, read this article using google translator (from russian) http://chikuyonok.ru/2010/11/optimization-story/

Solution:

1. Before animate you need to convert (temporarily) your float-right style into position:absolute without float. Maybe you need to compute future div dimensions (height/width) and use them in animation. Maybe you need to set fixed height to parent before animation.
2. Animate absolutely positioned div
3. After animations, convert position:absolute style back to float:right

It will be better if you start and end point static position will not have `style` attribute (all in css classes). In this case to restore standart style you just need to .removeAttr('style')